# How can a telegram bot receive photo which are attached to commands in telegram group chats without privacy mode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I want to make a telegram bot, that receives commands to which photos are attached. It should also work in groups. And if possible it would work with privacy-mode enabled. If possible it should work as a single message (e.g. not a separate message for the command and for the photo)

For example, when I send a photo to the bot with the command `/my_command my_string_parameter`, it would look like this:

[image: example of what it would look like to send a photo to the bot]

Here is an example code, except that in this example the method is only called, when the command is used WITHOUT a photo attached. How would I have to modify this example so it the method `my_command` is also called when a photo is sent?

```py
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import CallbackContext, CommandHandler, Updater

def my_command(update: Update, _: CallbackContext) -> None:
    # This is only called, when /my_command is used WITHOUT a photo attached
    update.message.reply_text("photo received?")

updater = Updater(secret.telegram_token)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("my_command", my_command))
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

Note: I am not restricted to the module `python-telegram-bot`, but I am restricted to python3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MessageHandler` with caption filter, which will contains your command, instead of `CommandHandler`.

Example:

```py
from telegram.ext.filters import Filters

dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.caption(update=['my_command']), my_command))
```

Comment: thanks. what exactly is a "caption" in telegram?  (this is not really related to the question, but I can't find a definition for it anywhere)

Comment: @wotanii caption is text but in messages with documents (photo, docs, videos etc.)